# Hover effect on svg image doesn't works on pages linked with Single Articles in Joomla

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, joomla3.0

In my Joomla Website :

I have **social icons** in the Footer of my site and those **images are in svg format**.

Now I need to **change** my images on **hovering**.

I have applied the following jquery, which **works fine on the home page**. But it **doesn't works on the menu's that has Menu Type as *Single Article***.

I've placed the jquery in my template's index file and the script is:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
      var sourcehover = function () {
        var $this = jQuery(this);
        var hoverimg = $this.data('alt-src');
        $this.data('alt-src', $this.attr('src'));
        $this.attr('src', hoverimg);
    };
    jQuery(function() {
        jQuery('img[data-alt-src]').each(function() { 
            new Image().src = jQuery(this).data('alt-src'); 
        }).hover(sourcehover); 
    });
    });
</script>
<div class="social clearfix"> 
      <a href="#" target="_blank">
         <img src="http://52.24.52.110/images/social-icons/fb.svg" alt="" width="32" height="32" data-alt-src="http://52.24.52.110/images/social-icons/fb_hover.svg" />
    </a>
    <a href="#" target="_blank">
      <img src="http://52.24.52.110/images/social-icons/google-plus.svg" alt="" width="32" height="32" data-alt-src="http://52.24.52.110/images/social-icons/googleplus_hover.svg" />
    </a>
    <a href="#" target="_blank">
      <img src="http://52.24.52.110/images/social-icons/youtube.svg" alt="" width="32" height="32" data-alt-src="http://52.24.52.110/images/social-icons/youtube_hover.svg" />
    </a>
    <a href="#" target="_blank">
      <img src="http://52.24.52.110/images/social-icons/pinterest.svg" alt="" width="32" height="32" data-alt-src="http://52.24.52.110/images/social-icons/pinterest_hover.svg" />
    </a>
    <a href="#" target="_blank">
      <img src="http://52.24.52.110/images/social-icons/instagram.svg" alt="" width="32" height="32" data-alt-src="http://52.24.52.110/images/social-icons/instagram_hover.svg" />
</a>
    <a href="#" target="_blank">
      <img src="http://52.24.52.110/images/social-icons/twitter.svg" alt="" width="32" height="32" data-alt-src="http://52.24.52.110/images/social-icons/twitter_hover.svg" />
    </a>

  <a href="#" target="_blank">
    <img src="http://52.24.52.110/images/social-icons/linkedin.svg" alt="" width="32" height="32" data-alt-src="http://52.24.52.110/images/social-icons/linkedin_hover.svg" />
     </a>
</div>
```

Comment: What does "doesn't works on the menu's that has Menu Type as Single Article" mean? What's Menu Type, what's a Single Article? And what part of the snippet demonstrates/reproduces the issue you're having? What should happen when I run the snippet that isn't currently happening?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention it was for Joomla. And Single Article is Menu type Category in joomla

Comment: The Snippet is working correctly, only for few pages.

Comment: Please create a snippet that doesn't work then so we can see what to fix.

Comment: "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/test/page1/images/social-icons/twitter_hover.svg" : This is what the error I get for the inner pages

Comment: The code is same, so I can't prepare another snippet for it.
Its just that it works for some pages and doesn't works on some page that are linked with articles in joomla

Answer (score 3):

This functionality doesn't need any JavaScript. You can get it by CSS.

```css
.social-icon {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-indent: 32px;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background-size: cover;
}
.fb {
  background-image: url(http://52.24.52.110/images/social-icons/fb.svg);
}
.fb:hover {
  background-image: url(http://52.24.52.110/images/social-icons/fb_hover.svg);
}
.googleplus {
  background-image: url(http://52.24.52.110/images/social-icons/google-plus.svg);
}
.googleplus:hover {
  background-image: url(http://52.24.52.110/images/social-icons/googleplus_hover.svg);
}
.youtube {
  background-image: url(http://52.24.52.110/images/social-icons/youtube.svg);
}
.youtube:hover {
  background-image: url(http://52.24.52.110/images/social-icons/youtube_hover.svg);
}
.pinterest {
  background-image: url(http://52.24.52.110/images/social-icons/pinterest.svg);
}
.pinterest:hover {
  background-image: url(http://52.24.52.110/images/social-icons/pinterest_hover.svg);
}
.instagram {
  background-image: url(http://52.24.52.110/images/social-icons/instagram.svg);
}
.instagram:hover {
  background-image: url(http://52.24.52.110/images/social-icons/instagram_hover.svg);
}
.twitter {
  background-image: url(http://52.24.52.110/images/social-icons/twitter.svg);
}
.twitter:hover {
  background-image: url(http://52.24.52.110/images/social-icons/twitter_hover.svg);
}
.linkedin {
  background-image: url(http://52.24.52.110/images/social-icons/linkedin.svg);
}
.linkedin:hover {
  background-image: url(http://52.24.52.110/images/social-icons/linkedin_hover.svg);
}
```

```html
<div class="social clearfix"> 
  <a href="#" target="_blank" class="social-icon fb">facebook</a>
  <a href="#" target="_blank" class="social-icon googleplus">googleplus</a>
  <a href="#" target="_blank" class="social-icon youtube">youtube</a>
  <a href="#" target="_blank" class="social-icon pinterest">pinterest</a>
  <a href="#" target="_blank" class="social-icon instagram">instagram</a>
  <a href="#" target="_blank" class="social-icon twitter">twitter</a>
  <a href="#" target="_blank" class="social-icon linkedin">linkedin</a>
</div>
```

The next step is combine images into SVG-sprite. It'll remove loading glitch and decrease amount of HTTP-requests.

Comment: How do you want to manage it? It didn't describe in your original question.